# How can I get a dialog's initial directory without opening the dialog in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, openfiledialog, windows-api-code-pack

Through ways I don't understand, whenever I open my `CommonOpenFileDialog` it opens to the last directory I was in. Awesome! I'd like to access this directory's path string before I open the dialog to show the current directory on screen. Is there a way to do this?

I've tried the following, but get an empty string.

```
var dialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog();
        outputPathTextBox.Text = dialog.InitialDirectory;
        dialog = null;
```

Comment: Whats wrong with saving the filename the time you close the FileDialog. The next time you'll have it without bothering the FileDialog

Comment: Nothing is wrong with that and that's what I ended up doing. I just thought that since the dialog seemed to know it anyway it would be cleaner to use its knowledge than track it myself. No big deal.